# Display a model's property from char to string using a dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a property in my class model that can contain 4 values, and i want to display it by using razor but change the value of it depending on the char, example :

if my class property's value is 'C' , i want to display it using razor so the result can be like this :  "Captured".

should i use Annotations? Foolproof package? i'm open to all ideas, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the logic in your model.  Additionally to reduce [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) don't use a switch statement.

```
public class MyModel
{
  private readonly Dictionary<char,string> _prop = new
    Dictionary<char, string>
    {
      { 'c', "Captured" }
    };

  public char MyValue { get; set; }

  public string MyValueDisplay 
  {
    get 
    {
      string result;
      if (!_prop.TryGetValue(MyValue, out result))
      {
        result = "Default Value";
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these values don't change much, there are a couple of ways that you can do it.
the first is to use a helper function to display what you want instead of the code value.
another method is to add a property on the model that takes the code value and returns the string value.
for example

```
public string Code {get; set;}

public string CodeName {get { 
switch(Code){
case "C":
return "Captured";
case "B"
return "blah"; 

}
```